# Is there a way to import .mx or .mxa files?

Tags: import

A game called Forsaken (1998) has models in **.mx** and **.mxa** format. Although I'm not sure what's the difference between them, I'd like to know if there's some import script available for them.

[image]

I searched for md3 importing scripts before, I bet there should be some for mx too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now there is a at least partially implemented importer (prints a lot of stuff to the console) All you need to do is copy the script in the editor and
edit this (last) line before pressing the run button:

```
importMX("c:\\path\\avatar.mx", 'Avatar')
```

The first argument is the path to the file to import, second the object name in Blender.

```
import bpy
import mathutils
import struct

def read_n_items(file, n, func):
    for i in range(n):
        func(i, file)

def read_struct_from_file(file, fmt):
    return struct.unpack(fmt, file.read(struct.calcsize(fmt)))

def skip_string(file):
    s=''
    while True:
        c = struct.unpack('c', file.read(1))[0]
        s = s + c.decode("utf-8")
        if c == b'\x00':
            print(s)
            return       

def importMX(filename, obj_name):
    verts=[]
    faces=[]
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        prjx = read_struct_from_file(file, '8ch')
        print(prjx)
        num_texture_files = prjx[8]
        print(num_texture_files)
        while num_texture_files > 0:
            num_texture_files = num_texture_files - 1
            skip_string(file)
            groups = read_struct_from_file(file, 'h')[0]
            exec_lists = read_struct_from_file(file, 'I')[0]
            exec_type = read_struct_from_file(file, 'h')[0]
            vertices = read_struct_from_file(file, 'h')[0]
            #groups,exec_lists,exec_type,vertices = read_struct_from_file(file, 'hIhh')
        print( 'vertices=%d' % vertices )
        idx=0 
        while idx < vertices:
            x,y,z,reserved,colour,specular,tu,tv = read_struct_from_file(file,'fffIIIII')
            print('%d %f %f %f' % (idx,x,y,z))   
            verts.append((x,y,z))
            idx = idx + 1

        num_tex_groups = read_struct_from_file(file, 'h')[0]
        print(num_tex_groups)

        while num_tex_groups > 0:
            texture_type,start_vertex,num_vertices,texture_no,num_triangles = read_struct_from_file( file, 'hhhhh' )
            num_tex_groups = num_tex_groups - 1
            print( "tt=%d sv=%d nv=%d tno=%d tria=%d" % (texture_type,start_vertex,num_vertices,texture_no,num_triangles ))
            while num_triangles > 0:
                v0,v1,v2,pa = read_struct_from_file( file, 'hhhh' )
                nx,ny,nz = read_struct_from_file( file, 'fff' )
                print('%d,%d,%d %f %f %f' %  (v0,v1,v2,nx,ny,nz))
                num_triangles = num_triangles - 1
                faces.append((v0,v1,v2))                
        print(verts)
        print(faces)
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new( obj_name )
        object = bpy.data.objects.new( obj_name, mesh)
        object.location = (0,0,0)  
        bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)
        mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    importMX("c:\\path\\avatar.mx", 'Avatar')
```

Result:

avatar.mx

[image]

airmoble.mx

[image]

To get started you can extend on the following code, there is also an undocumented 8 byte "PRJX...." id at beginning of the file besides that the format seems to match.

See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html for the format strings like: h=uint16 and I=uint32 etc.
[image]

Comment: Looking forward to try the code tonight. :)

Comment: Should I put the file inside some of the blender's folders and run it somehow within Blender, or just run it within python command line? I don't know how to proceed either way though.

Comment: [I'm having problems when trying to import bpy](http://i.imgur.com/HKWmROj.png)

Comment: @Fabián You need to run it from Blenders text editor, not the console window. Added image to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The .mx format and the animated variant .mxa are documented in the sources:

- [File-format - .mx](https://github.com/ForsakenX/forsaken/wiki/File-format:-mx)
- [File-format - .mxa](https://github.com/ForsakenX/forsaken/wiki/File-format:-mxa)

The binary format looks different to the Blender supported formats (at least the ones I have seen so far). You would need to write a custom importer.

```
num_texture_files : uint16
texture_file_name[num_texture_files] : '\\0' separated strings
num_groups : uint16
{
    num_exec_lists : uint16
    {
      exec_type : uint32 // 0 = entirely opaque, 1 = contains transparencies
      num_vertices : uint16
      vertex(x,y,z,reserved,colour,specular,tu,tv)[num_vertices] : x, y, z float, others uint32
      num_texture_groups : uint16
      {
        texture_type : uint16 // 0 = normal, 1 = environment mapped
        start_vertex : uint16
        num_vertices : uint16
        texture_no : uint16
        num_triangles : uint16
        triangles(v0,v1,v2,pad16,nx,ny,nz)[num_triangles] : v? uint16, pad16 uint16, n? float
      }[num_texture_groups]
    }[num_exec_lists]
}[num_groups]
mxtype : uint16 // always 0 for mx format
```

The sources of the [.MD3 addon](https://github.com/neumond/blender-md3) show that this format has a at least comparable structure.

Comment: @Fabián the itself format isn't C it is pseudo code. To import the mesh only you would need to skip the texture names and read the vertices num_vertices times. The .MD3 addon has all the code snippets you would need.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that, although I'm not within the import/export scripting subject, I'm still noob at programming. I was just hoping to insert one file in which makes Blender be able to import the model to begin work with.

Comment: ok I recently saw the new comment, I'll give it a try