# Reversing a 3d model

Tags: modeling

I want to know how to reverse a 3d model,for example some guys develop scripts and tools to extract 3d models from video games and then convert them to obj and stuff.I have no knowledge in these things apart from making edits using blender.
So i wanna know where do i start to learn 3d model reversing.

Comment: Wouldn't that be copyright infringement?...

Comment: i'm not sure I understand the question yet. Do you want to learn to code so as to be able to extract models, or do you want to learn how to accurately recreate models purely from references using modelling skills? You can improve modeling skills by going through our [list of Blender resources](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: and I don't read the word blender anywhere... so I vote to close the question.

Comment: @m.ardito but Blender is mentioned in the second last sentence. I agree with the sentiment to close or put on hold...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad. You would need to know the file format, and create an importer for this format in Blender. As an example: Starting with a documentation of the .mx format I created a script to import the models of an old game called forsaken. The source and links to the documentation are linked here:

[Is there a way to import .mx or .mxa files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26474/is-there-a-way-to-import-mx-or-mxa-files)